# join using lambda expressions and retrieving the data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, lambda

I have a `members` table with columns

```
  member_Id,
  member_Lastname,
  member_Firstname,
  member_Postcode,
  member_Reference,
  member_CardNum,
```

and i have another table `mshipoptions` with columns

```
mshipoption_id
mshiptype_id
```

and i have another table `mshiptypes`

```
 mshiptype_id
 mshiptype_name
```

another table `memtomship`

```
 memtomship_id
 mshipoption_id
 member_id
```

and my entity name is `eclipse`

at the form load i am filling the datagrid view by using the below method....

```
private void reportmembers()
{
        MemberControlHelper.Fillmembershiptypes(cbGEMembershiptype); 
        var membersreport = from tsgentity in eclipse.members
                                join memtomships in eclipse.membertomships on tsgentity.member_Id equals memtomships.member_Id
                                join mshipoptiions in eclipse.mshipoptions on memtomships.mshipOption_Id equals mshipoptiions.mshipOption_Id
                                join mshiptypes in eclipse.mshiptypes on mshipoptiions.mshipType_Id equals mshiptypes.mshipType_Id
                                select 
                                new {                                     
                                    tsgentity.member_Id,
                                    tsgentity.member_Lastname,
                                    tsgentity.member_Firstname,
                                    tsgentity.member_Postcode,
                                    tsgentity.member_Reference,
                                    tsgentity.member_CardNum,
                                   mshiptypes.mshipType_Name,                                   
                                };

           if (txtfirstname.Text != "")
           {
              dgvmembersrep.DataSource = membersreport.Where(t => t.member_Firstname == txtlastname.Text).ToList();                
           }
           if (txtcardnum.Text != "")
           { 
                dgvmembersrep.DataSource = membersreport.Where(a => a.member_CardNum == txtcardnum.Text).ToList(); 
           }
}
```

that was fine,...

My problem is here , i have  one comboboxsay (cbgemembershiptype)......

when ever the user select the membership type in (cbgemembershiptype) i want retrieve the details of members those who have that membership type....

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Your question is unclear in terms of whether the query you've got already does what you want. I'm assuming it does.)

It's unclear why you'd *want* to convert this query into one using lambda expressions. It's certainly possible, but each join would introduce a new range variable - by the end, the strictly literal translation would end up with a select involving something like

```
member_Id = a.b.c.member_Id
```

... it wouldn't be very readable at all.

There are ways of improving it if you're writing it out by hand, but it still wouldn't be as clear as the query expression.

You should definitely know both forms, and write using whichever form is clearest for the query in question - which in this case is definitely the query expression form.

For more information about how query expressions are translated, see my [Edulinq post on that topic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx).

Comment: would you pls see my modified code , i am not sure whether it is correct or not to check the member first name and card num , and i dont know how to chekc mship type name .. would you pls give any sample code or any idea ....

Comment: @errorstacks: Sorry, your question is very unclear. Please concentrate on rewriting it as clearly as possible - read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I have modified my query , do u have any idea how to retrive the member details with member ship type whoose have membership type select in combobox.....i know it includes join but i dont know how to do..

Comment: @errorstacks: Sorry, it's *still* taking me too much time to read the question - partly because you haven't bothered with capitalization, formatting your code so we can see all of it without scrolling etc. It sounds petty, but it really makes it harder to answer.